# Выборка по типу MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго времени суток. Помогите, пожалуйста, составить правильный SQL запрос.

Есть рабочий запрос:

```
SELECT orders.order_id, orders.typeorder, customers.name, orders.customer_id 
FROM orders 
LEFT JOIN customers ON customers.customer_id = orders.customer_id".$status." 
LIMIT $start_pos, $perpage
```

Как только я хочу добавить в

```
SELECT orders.order_id, orders.typeorder, customers.name, orders.customer_id 
FROM orders
```

строку

```
WHERE orders.typeorder = '3'
```

выборка вообще ничего не выводит.
Спасибо за внимание!

Answer (score 1):

Судя по запаху, это у нас пхп.

1. Перед тем, как добавлять строки в запрос, следует изучить синтаксис SQL и выяснить, какой оператор должен идти первым, а какой - после него. В частности, JOIN и WHERE.
2. Вместо "ничего не выводит" код должен выводить сообщение об ошибке. А заодно и сам запрос. чтобы не на словах рассказывать "вот я тута вставляю это", а просто показать нерабочий запрос.